# 401 en peticion POST aplicación Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, jwt, headers

Estoy intentando realizar una petición a una API Springboot pero la petición arroja un error 401. La autenticación es con JWT y estoy guardando la token en localStorage. Pareciera ser que no la está enviando en el header pero no estoy seguro, soy muy nuevo creando aplicaciones en Ionic y programando en general, por lo que he a pesar a buscar información por todas partes no he podido hacerla funcionar correctamente.

Así tengo el servicio que me trae los datos (usuario logueado previamente)

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AddGeneralSpace } from '../models/add-general-space';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewGeneralSpaceService {

  idUser;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public newGeneralSpace(newGeneralSpace: AddGeneralSpace): Observable<any> {
    this.idUser = window.localStorage.getItem('AuthIdUser');
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios/' + this.idUser + '/sectoresGenerales', newGeneralSpace);
  }
}
```

así esta el método donde armo la solicitud:

```
 addGeneralSpace() {
    this.addGeneralSpaceModel = new AddGeneralSpace(this.nomSectorGnral, this.valorKwh, this.fechaIngresoValorKwh, this.mtrsCuadrados, this.totalConsumoW, this.totalPesos);
    console.log(this.addGeneralSpaceModel);
    this.newGeneralSpaceService.newUser(this.addGeneralSpaceModel).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.successToast();
        // setTimeout(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        // }, 1000);
      },
      err => {
        this.vaciar();
        this.errorToast();
      }
    )
    // this.router.navigate(['./dashboard']);
  }
```

y finalmente esto es el mensaje que me muestra en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pudieran ayudarme con esto se los agradecería muchisimo!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente logre solucionarlo añadiendo lo siguiente a la petición en el service:

```
let token = "Bearer "+ window.localStorage.getItem('AuthToken');
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": token
});
```

y en la peticion como tal:

```
{headers: headers}
```

Quedando el servicio finalmente de la siguiente forma:

```
export class NewGeneralSpaceService {

  idUser;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public newGeneralSpace(newGeneralSpace: AddGeneralSpace): Observable<any> {
    let token = "Bearer "+ window.localStorage.getItem('AuthToken');
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": token
    });
    this.idUser = window.localStorage.getItem('AuthIdUser');
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios/' + this.idUser + '/sectoresGenerales', newGeneralSpace, {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

No se si sea la mejor forma de solucionarlo pero bueno, espero a alguien le sirva!